# Sine wave using one register

Tags: assembly, 8051

So I was tasked with creating a sine wave I came up with this which uses two registers and works...

```
 DAC    EQU 0600h   ;DAC memory mapped at address 600h
tbl_len EQU 24  ;length of sine wave table

    ORG 8100H       ;start of program

sine:   mov R7, #tbl_len    ;initialise table counter
    mov R6, #0  ;initialise table pointer

sloop:  mov dptr, #table    ;load dptr with address of table
    mov a, R6   ;load acc with table pointer
    movc    a, @a+dptr  ;read from table + table pointer

    mov dptr, #DAC  ;load dptr with 0600 DAC base address
    movx    @dptr, a    ;Output table value from DAC
    acall   delay
    inc R6  ;inc table pointer
    djnz    R7, sloop   ;dec table counter until zero
    sjmp  sine  ;Repeat loop

delay:  mov R0, #11
loop:   djnz    R0, dloop   ;go around this loop 11 times
    ret

table:  DB  1,5,18,38,65,95,128,161,192,218,238,251
    DB  255,251,238,218,192,161,128,95,65,38,18,5
```

Now I have been asked to use only one register. I am a little confused even though I get the sense that it might be quite a simple solution. Any hints would be great.

Comment: you can simply use `R6` and compare after `inc R6` against the `#tbl_len` and branch (for example) if not equal. in this case there is no need to use `R7` anymore.

Comment: Thank you, that makes a lot of sense. Can't believe I didn't see that.